# PHP Mysql update table from data in two other tables

Tags: php, mysql

i am trying to update a table trough data found in two other tables.

```
UPDATE product
INNER JOIN stock ON product.id_product = stock.id_product
INNER JOIN input ON stock.ean13 = input.ean13
SET product.price = input.price
```

So how does it needs to work:

i have a table **product** which contains fields **id_product** & **price**

i have a table **stock** which contains fields **id_product** & **ean13**

i have a table **input** which contains field **price** & **ean13**

so in order to update **product.price**

i need to check if **stock.ean13** = **input.ean13**

if this is true it needs to grab **input.price** and **SET** **product.price** WHERE **product.id_product** = **stock.id_product**

hope i written enough information

Comment: Your query seems right to me. Do you get any error? What's your issue?

Comment: After a long search i noticed there is another table handling this data, i needed to update the price value in product_shop instead of product ...

Comment: I don't get the problem. Just change table name if they have same structure.

Comment: yeah, i solved it now, not sure on how to mark this topic as solved :)

Comment: You can answer your own questions :)

Comment: i looked at "edit" post an on the topic it self but cant find it :/

Comment: You don't need to edit the question. Post an answer containing solution you found. :)